# Can I disable automatic "copy/look up/share" on my iPhone SE?

Tags: iphone, ios, text

The "copy/look up/share" pops up when I am reading and scrolling and I never want it to.

Answer (score 5):

It's not automatic, it shows when you highlight some text, by holding down on a paragraph of selectable text. It's not possible to disable this action.

One failure mode of the digitizer is that it will select areas on the screen randomly - if you open up an app like the calculator - if buttons there get pressed randomly when you aren’t actively moving a digit on the screen, that’s a good indicator your hardware is failing.